# In Visual Studio, how can I stop the Commands and Description sections from keep coming back in Properties?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 (and indeed, all other versions) the Properties panel has a section of wasted space at the bottom, in which a description of the currently-selected property is shown.

You can right-click in the Properties panel and uncheck "Commands" and "Description" from the popup menu to hide these pointless sections and free up that wasted screen space for actual useful properties.

But Visual Studio doesn't remember this setting. So every single time I open Visual Studio (all versions), I have to go hide those sections again.

How do I get VS to remember my choice? (I tried googling, and got no results even *tangentially related* to my issue.)